# postgresql service corrupt, how can i re-create service?

Tags: windows-xp, postgresql, windows-service

I recently was tricked into running one of those registry cleaner programs (RegistryBooster).

It seemed to work fine until I tried to start my postgres service.

For some reason, the 'path to executable' was no longer set on the service properties page, and obviously would not start without a path.

How can I either fix the existing service or uninstall/ re-install just the service without re-installing postgres altogether?

postgres 8.4
windows xp sp3

**EDIT:**
in trying to fix this, i've accidentally removed the service altogether. so the question becomes: how do i re-install the service without re-installing the whole of postgres?

thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add/change key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\pgsql-8.4\ImagePath" in registry(change version and data dir):

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -w -N "pgsql-8.4" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\data\"
```

or run command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\pg_ctl.exe" runservice -w -N "pgsql-8.4" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\data\"

If not help, you will need to reinstall PostgreSQL.

Comment: sorry, please see edit: i've actually deleted the service trying to resolve the issue...

Comment: ah, i sorted it.. having deleted the service, i changed your command from `runservice` to `register` .. the service is created and works fine :) thx.

Answer (score 0):

I've had two different installs of PostgreSQL where the service has eventually spontaneously stopped working, I think due to permissions issues after a major Windows update (and definitely not due to a registry cleaner!).

But anyway, I thought it was worth flagging up that what @pstanton's says in the comment to @alvosu's answer is really a better answer, namely:

To remove the service:

```
pg_ctl unregister -N "PostgreSQL 9.6 Server"
```

(use the short name that your service actually has)

then to reinstall it

```
pg_ctl register -N "PostgreSQL 9.6 Server"
```

You need to add the flag `-D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\pg96"` (or whatever the correct path is) to the register command if you do not have the `PGDATA` environment variable set.